# What is the actual difference between RTMFP and BitTorrent?

Tags: flash, bittorrent

What can BitTorrent do that RTMFP cannot? And what can RTMFP do that BitTorrent cannot?

Answer (score 0):

RTMFP is a proprietary protocol that requires Flash to work right now (more or less). It can only be used for Flash videos. On the other hand, BitTorrent is an open protocol, you can implement in your C#, Perl or Python application as you'd like. And by being proprietary, and not reverse engineered yet AFAIK, you don't know that much about the differences yet. RTMFP is supposed to handle outages better so that your videos run smooth even if there's an outage, and that's about it.